# FSL Assignments

Tags: geolocation

My organization is now on Salesforce. FSL assigns calls based on the drivers original location.  We are seeing our drivers pulled from one side of the state to the other when there are drivers who are closer to the assignment available.  Is there a setting to allow FSL to assign based on the present location of the drivers?